Making a canonical question+answer pair for "is brain computer?"
@ArnonWeinberg is admirably trying to make a canonical question+answer pair for questions comparing the human brain to a computer. This question allows us to quickly close similar questions as duplicates. I would like to discuss this question and it's format here.
Specifically, I feel the current format could be improved. I agree with @StevenJeuris about formatting the Question and Answer pair. I think a big general question, with specific sub-categorized answers would be helpful. Personally, I see the questions breaking down into:

How does the brain use it's resources (processing, memory) compared to a computer
How are brain algorithms different than computer algorithms.

I think the first question is definitely worth a canonical answer. However, I feel some questions under the second answer are acceptable as they are asking for example cognitive models. For example, I consider "How does the brain generate answers to questions?" and "How does a human classify or cluster data?" to be useful. Consequently, I don't think they should be closed as duplicates of the canonical question. However, I think "What is the data structure used by the brain to store data?" and "Does the brain have a 'debugging mode'?" are be based on the fallacy of the brain being a computer and should be closed as duplicates.
Does anyone else have other suggestions or concerns about this canonical question?

I agree - there are many good posts on the list that would not be beneficial to close as duplicates.
PS: Feel free to convert the question to community wiki so that everyone can update it however is desired.

Well, I just closed a recent question as a duplicate of the canonical question which I deemed fairly appropriate. So, I guess it is working. :)
